# Replace HTML tags preserving their content using lxml

Tags: python, lxml

I have some html content (without html, body and head etc. tags). What I need to do is strip style information from tags and also replace div tags with p tags.

I am striping style information using:

```
from lxml.html.clean import Cleaner
return Cleaner(style=True).clean_html(html)
```

How can I replace the div tags with p tags while preserving the content of div tags (content of div tags should be in new p tags).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). It is a python library that can use multiple html parsers but I used LXML with it. Here is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
for tag in soup():
    del tag['style']
    del tag['class']
    if tag.name == 'div':
        tag.name = 'p'
return soup.body.encode_contents()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
html = html.replace("<div>", "<p>")
html = html.replace("</div>", "</p>")
```

You could do it with full-blown HTML parsing and generating, but probably the above will do OK for this.

Comment: If there *is* `<div>` in text it would probably be `&lt;div&gt;` or whatever, so this will still work.

Comment: Yes this is the simplest solution but there always can be some attributes in <div> that is why I want to do it using lxml parsing instead of string replacement

Comment: @MuhammadTahirButt: well then by all means go ahead and write the code to do that.

Comment: @John Zwinck: that is where I need help to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
el = node.cssselect('span')
for e in el:
     e.tag = 'p'
```

eTree has an easy way built in to accomplish switching the tag. You can just set the tag parameter. Below is a sample of what my element list looks like after one iteration just to show that it does switch it to a p tag.

Link to documentation: https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#elementpath (shows eTree.tag function, but I didn't see it show you could set the value as well)

```
<class 'list'>: [<Element p at 0x22eb9bc0f40>, <Element span at 0x22eb9bc0ea0>, <Element span at 0x22eba4114f0>, <Element span at 0x22eba411630>, <Element span at 0x22eba411680>, <Element span at 0x22eba4116d0>, <Element span at 0x22eba411720>, <Element span at 0x22eba411770>, <Element span at 0x22eba4117c0>, <Element span at 0x22eba411810>, <Element span at 0x22eba411860>, <Element span at 0x22eba4118b0>, <Element span at 0x22eba411900>, <Element span at 0x22eba411950>, <Element span at 0x22eba4119a0>, <Element span at 0x22eba4119f0>, <Element span at 0x22eba411a40>, <Element span at 0x22eba411a90>, <Element span at 0x22eba411ae0>, <Element span at 0x22eba411b30>, <Element span at 0x22eba411b80>, <Element span at 0x22eba411bd0>, <Element span at 0x22eba411c20>]
<Element p at 0x22eb9bc0f40>
<Element span at 0x22eb9bc0ea0>
```